# Access old SQL Server 2000 database locked for one user

Tags: sql-server, delphi, encryption, sql-server-2000, decompiling

I have an old Delphi application which uses SQL Server 2000 Developer edition, with no Windows authentication access and no `sa` user, only one user at the server, the `appuser`, only the application can access the server and the database using this user and password.

I've tried to add the local admin to the server using sqlcm (starting SQL Server in single user mode), but it's not supported in SQL Server 2000.

The connection string is encrypted in setting.ini file

I'm looking for anyway to decrypt the connection string or add the Windows admin user to SQL Server as admin

I want to attach another db to the same server without interrupting the delphi application

Comment: and you don't have source code of the application?

Comment: a) What exact error message or other problem do you get when the app attempts to connect to the server?  b) Do you have the source code of the application?  c)  Have you tried using the Sql Profiler to see if you can monitor what your app sends to the server?  d) If the app used to work but now doesn't, what has changed that might account for the difference?  All of these details should be in your q, imo.  Btw, I may be wrong but iirc the SA account couldn't be removed in SS 2K.

Comment: according to question I think the app is able to connect to database. but he lost the password and not able to do any more changes to the database and connection string is encrypted so he can't recover the password.

Comment: @Yeou
No, I don't have the code

Comment: @MartynA - I have not tried sql profiler, the app works fine , I need to access the server and the db without interupting the app

Comment: @JackJ are you sure the setting.ini is encrypted and not binary data? 1. If the connection string is stored using the binary writer, you can try writing binary reader. 
2. if its encrypted, then you need to find out which algorithm is used to encrypt it so you can reverse the process.

Comment: Try attaching the physical files to a later instance to which you DO have access. You will need to stop the 2000 instance to do this.You won't be able to do this with current versions of sql server but perhaps you have an older one (2008, 2008r2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](https://www.0xsql.com/2012/01/20/on-the-topic-of-lost-sa-passwords-on-sql-server-2000/) describes how to get a password of any active session in a windows 2000 instance by sifting though a dump file of the sqlservr.exe process.

In general you:

1. Download this process dump utility from Microsoft Sysinternals called [ProcDump v9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)
2. Log on as local admin and open a command prompt
3. Execute this command: 
   `procdump -ma sqlservr.exe`
4. Download [Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings)
5. Find the generated .dmp file in the procdump folder and rename it to file.dmp then Execute this command: 
   `strings file.dmp > dump.txt`
6. Open dump.txt with notepad and search for the hostname concatenated with the username.  You should find the password immediately following that string.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try also to use some kernel-debugger and debug Delphi app to find and read the decrypted password from the memory before it is sent to the server. You need to know Assembly language in depth in order to debug it.

2) As was already stated by SMor in the comments, try to re-attach the data files and transaction log to other SQL instance which is under your control.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to add the local admin to the server using sqlcm (starting
>   SQL Server in single-user mode), but it's not supported in SQL Server
>   2000.

SQL Server 2000 supports a single user mode, therefore a traditional way of unlocking SQL Server box should be also applied here.

It can be enabled by

1. starting the service in the console by running

   ```
   sqlservr.exe -m
   ```
2. Connecting via console client tool:

   ```
   osql -E -S.
   ```

   The challenge with this step is to establish a very first user connection because the service is in a "Single User" mode so it will accept the first one and refuse all other incoming connections
3. Adding a login

   ```
   EXEC master..sp_addlogin @loginame='Domain\Account'
   ```
4. Granting SYSADMIN rights to a login

   ```
   EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'Domain\Account', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
   ```
5. Stop the service, by hitting `CTRL-C`
6. Start the service in a regular way, connect to it via client tools and attach another database

Comment: I got login failed for user, and I've tried -m"OSQL" and -m"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" and I've ran both as admin ,with no hope!